# New to OOP & Python -- Question About Storing Lots of Objects

Tags: python, oop

I've just started out with Python and programming and I have a general question about storing many objects.

My understanding of objects so far is thus:  I can define an object like:

```
class Meal:
```

And have functions on it such that I can find out about it for example Meal.drink returns 'soda' and Meal.main returns 'pizza'.  So far, so good.

However, I'm not sure that I'm doing the right thing when it comes to storing lots of objects.   Right now, I'm keeping them all in a list so that every time I want to record a new meal I do:

```
temp = Meal()

listOfMeals.append(temp)
```

If I want to find out how many times I've had soda in all the recorded meals I iterate through the list and count:

```
for each in listOfMeals

    if each.drink == 'soda':

        sodaCount = sodaCount + 1
```

Is this the best way to handle long lists of objects?  It feels a bit clunky to me, but since I have no experience with object-oriented programming (and little programming experience in general) I'm not sure if I've overlooked something obvious.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: you can use `listOfMeals.append(Meal())` rather than creating a temporary object.

Comment: You have the right idea. The only variation from here is how you implement this idea (the variou python builtins that you choose to or not to use).

Comment: There are some clever solutions below, but unless speed is an issue for your program, your solution is fine.

Comment: Your code is perfectly good. Maybe 'meal' would be a better variable name than 'each'.

Answer (score 6):

It depends what you are going for. *Every* piece of code can be written more efficiently, but the question you should always ask yourself first is: Why does this code have to be faster?

If there is no reason to make that method faster (because the count is not used that much, the list of meals has just a hundred entries anyways, etc), you should just go with something simple like

```
sodacount = sum(1 for meal in listOfMeals if meal.drink=='soda')
```

On the other hand, if you need that count very often, you could wrap your list of meals in another object that stores and updates the count:

```
class MealList(object):
    # insert __init__, etc.

    def addMeal(self, meal):
        self._meals.append(meal)
        # update the count
        self.counts[meal.drink] += 1

    # insert method to remove meals

meals = MealList()
# add meals etc ....
print meals.counts['soda']
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a ORM such as [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) will allow you to store all this in a database, which can then help speed up certain types of queries ("Find all Meals where the drink attribute is 'soda'.").

Answer (score 1):

You can also write the counting loop in "functional" style, then you don't even need `sodaCount` var.

```
def count_sodas(meals):
  return reduce(lambda count, meal: count + (1 if meal.drink == 'soda' else 0),
                meals, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in your code. It is not very idiomatic but is Ok. If you have no problem with slowness, just use it this way you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea. There are a few points I would make:

1. When defining a class, 'inherit' from object (or another class) thus `class Meal(object):`
2. You say that `drink` and `main` are functions. If they are, ensure you call them when you want to refer to the return value. `meal.drink == 'soda'` should be `meal.drink() == 'soda'`
3. Unless there is a good reason for these attributes of a meal to be a function (i.e. you need to calculate them), they should probably be simple 'instance attributes' of the Meal object.

If you find there are a number of common operations you need to perform on the list of meals it might be useful to wrap the list of meals with a custom object `Meals`. You can then add your own methods. For example, you may regularly need to find all '3-course' meals:

```
class Meals(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.meals = []
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.meals)
    def three_course(self):
        return [m for m in self.meal if m.starter and m.main and m.dessert]
```

This is a fairly contrived example but you should get the idea. Also note that there are loads of ways of doing this; you may want to subclass a list rather than wrap it. If you are storing meal data in a database, consider the answer from @Ignacio. SQLAlchemy is great, and can be as simple or complex as you need it to be.

Comment: `meal.drink() == 'soda'`? are you sure that's what you meant?

Comment: Yes, if as the OP says Meal.drink is a "function". Granted, that is not good code. My point was that if they really _are_ callables, they need to be called.